# dc.js and crossfilter reduce average counts per day of week

Tags: javascript, dc.js, crossfilter

I am struggle to get my crossfilter groups set up right. Maybe someone can drop a hint!

My datastructure looks more or less this way:

```
{datetime: "2014-01-01 20:00:00", id:1}
{datetime: "2014-01-01 22:21:08", id:2}
{datetime: "2014-01-02 12:00:23", id:3} etc...
```

The dimension is on datetime to return the day of week:

```
var weekdayDimension = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return new Date(d.datetime).getDay();
});
```

Now I have problems with the grouping. I want the average count of events per weekday. So far I have (of course no correct)

```
var weekdayAvgGroup = weekdayDimension.group(function (d) {
    return d;
});
```

I think I do not understand what that grouping is doing exactly...

**My goal** is to have some chart like:

```
Monday => Average 40.3 Events
Tuesday => Average 35.4 Events
```

I created a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wz3o4jgy/) please take a look.

Can anybody drop a hint please?

**UPDATE:**

After additional thinking I could create a dimension on the Date. All I would have to do is to know the number of days selected in order to calculate the

```
(total amount of events selected/number of selected days)
```

So I would need to count the number of groups on the date dimension. But haven't found the solution on this one either.

Thank you

Comment: If you only use the datetime, the only thing you can compute is the count (per week, per weekday, per month, per year etc.). You can't compute an average.

Comment: After a bit of thinking: the only thing I would need additionally is the number of days selected. Isn't that correct? So if I would create a dimension on the date how do I get the numbers of selected days...

Comment: Still not clear enough for me I'm afraid :/ Maybe explain from the data how you get to 40.3 and 35.4

Comment: I've completely revised my answer below, because I realized you're talking about a second-level aggregation, which is a bit more of a challenge. Probably too late, but I thought I'd give it another shot in case it helps someone else.

Answer (score 6):

The annotated stock example shows how to do averages:
http://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/stock.html

Basically you will use a custom reduce function, maintain a count and a sum, and divide the sum by the count (if the count is greater than zero) to get an average.

Reductio also makes this pretty easy:
https://github.com/esjewett/reductio

EDIT: Looking back on this, I notice you mean the average of the aggregated counts, across the unique dates for each day of the week.

I know it's too late, but since we get a fair number of these "second-level aggregation" questions, I thought I'd answer this one, in case it helps someone else.

So, our results should bin the data on the day of the week, so we'll set up our dimension and group accordingly:

```
// dimension on day of week
var dim1 = ndx.dimension(function(d) {
    return d[0].getDay();
});
// group on day of week
var grp1 = dim1.group().reduce(
    ... // what goes here?
);
```

But how do we do the second-level aggregation? Already crossfilter is going to give all the entries for each day of the week, efficiently. What we need to do is count the entries per unique date.

We can use `d3.map` for this. We'll first use `d3.time.day` to remove the time-of-day info, then use `.getTime()` to get an integer we can index on. Then `d3.map` creates the "all Mondays", "all Tuesdays" bins:

```
var grp1 = dim1.group().reduce(
    function(p, v) { // add
        var day = d3.time.day(v[0]).getTime();
        p.map.set(day, p.map.has(day) ? p.map.get(day) + 1 : 1);
        p.avg = average_map(p.map);
        return p;
    },
    function(p, v) { // remove
        var day = d3.time.day(v[0]).getTime();
        p.map.set(day, p.map.has(day) ? p.map.get(day) - 1 : 0);
        p.avg = average_map(p.map);
        return p;
    },
    function() { // init
        return {map: d3.map(), avg: 0};
    }
);
```

Finally, we'll compute the average of all bins in the `d3.map` with this function:

```
function average_map(m) {
    var sum = 0;
    m.forEach(function(k, v) {
        sum += v;
    });
    return m.size() ? sum / m.size() : 0;
}
```

It might not be so efficient to walk the `d3.map` every time a day is added, so the call to `average_map` could be moved into the `valueAccessor` we'll use in the chart. I'll leave that as an exercise.

Here is a fiddle demonstrating the technique:
http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/0woyhg3n/11/

And applied to the original fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gordonwoodhull/pkh03azq/6/

Comment: Thanks. Your average_map function uses the whole map size, which does not exclude the bins that have a 0-value. So averages seem to be wrong when more filters are applied.

The issue is that the 'remove' callback does not tell if the record is not there anymore because the data has changed or because the filters have changed. Once could use crossfilter.isElementFiltered(index), provided you add the index in all records, and either remove the day from the map or just decrement the value.

Comment: Actually, the community fork of crossfilter does provide that info. Check out the [`nf` parameter here](https://github.com/crossfilter/crossfilter/wiki/API-Reference#group_reduce). It's been a while but I'll try to see if this answer needs revising tomorrow. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Ah, thank you indeed, it works. Oddly enough, in my test, the nf value passed to the remove callback was either undefined (for filtered out) or true (for data removal), but that will do the job.

Comment: Actually, to fully achieve the computation of averages that exclude filtered out data, the technique I suggested above is not correct, because those filters might exclude bins that have no data, ie. remove() is not called.
So, instead, I modified my average_map() algorithm to include only counts and keys for which the key is compatible with the current dc.js filters.

Comment: I don't understand why it's not sufficient to check if `p.map.get(day)` is 1. If so, remove the map entry. If not, decrement as before. As you write above. Why is it also necessary to know which records are filtered? You will get an add for every record included, and a remove for every record excluded, should be enough?

Comment: Oh... There are two issues. The other is getting an accurate count of all days within the time range, which you are right, crossfilter won't give you - it will only count dates for which there are data. One solution, not very elegant, is to create dummy rows with zeroes so that every date is represented.

Comment: Another is to count #days within the date range - [d3.interval.count](https://github.com/d3/d3-time/blob/master/README.md#interval_count) gives you this but you have to calculate it for every weekday every time the date range changes. I don't understand why you'd want to consider the other filters as well.

Comment: As for why: let's say we have these data: ```week #1: 10 events on Monday, 30 events on Tuesday```, ```week #2: 50 on Monday, 0 on Tuesday```. Without any filter, the computed averages are Mondays: 30, Tuesdays: 15.

Now, we filter on the week and keep only week #1. That means we are not interested at all by the data of week #2. The averages should show: Mondays: 10, Tuesdays: 30. But if we don't correlate the bins and the current filters, we would get Mondays: 5 (because all the second week's Monday events were removed but we kept the bin), Tuesdays: 15 (no events were removed / 2 bins).

Comment: Yeah I get that. I was trying to make a distinction between the date range and any other filters. I thought you meant you needed to consider other unrelated dimension filters too. I agree you need to look at the date range specially and count weekdays within it, and `nf` doesn't help with that.